# Sequelize: How to reverse query in hasMany?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following models:

```
const Users = sequelize.define('User', {/* ... */})
const Articles = sequelize.define('Articles', {/* ... */})
```

I have a association between them as follow:

```
Users.hasMany(Articles, { as: 'Post' })
```

which adds a foreignKey 'userId' in the Articles table.

Now I can eager load the articles when querying via the User model as:

```
Users.findOne({ where: { id: 'user_one'}, includes: [{ model: Articles }] })
```

But how can I do the reverse i.e:

```
Articles.findAll({ where: { id: 'user_one', includes: [{ model: Users }] }})
```

Comment: So, what you want here is to find all articles by a certain user?

Comment: no. i want the associated user detail when i retrieve the article list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's basically how to query it, in which it's similar to yours:

```
Articles.findAll({
    where: { userID: 'user_one' },
    include: [{
        model: Users,
        required: true
    }]
})
```

But I have the following for my table relationships:

```
Users.hasMany(Articles, { foreignKey: 'userID' });
Articles.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: 'userID' });
```

Comment: thanks. it worked after adding the belongsTo relation

Answer (score 0):

Just use, `include` instead if `includes`

```
Articles.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Users,
        where: { id: 'user_one' }
    }]
})
```

In the above, `id` is primary key in that `Articles` table.

[Here is a good discussion for that](https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/83b554ee08726a734088d90d455bc566)